# How to clean up thousands of Facebook notification emails in Yahoo mail box?

Tags: yahoo-mail

Currently, my Yahoo mail box is full of Facebook notification messages.

I tried to create a filter to move them to a separate folder but it is not applicable for current messages already in the inbox (see details [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100314131937AAgxwTr)).

So my question is: how can I clean up those thousands of such emails?

Comment: I don't use Yahoo, and this is probably a last-resort ... but a thought is to connect a desktop mail app such as Outlook to your Yahoo account via IMAP - and then do a search/filter + bulk delete.

Comment: Where can I turn on IMAP access for Yahoo mail? @DaveClausen

Comment: I've just check mail setting and all I can see is the POP access option, no IMAP there @DaveClausen

Comment: As mentioned, I don't use Yahoo, but a quick search found this: http://email.about.com/od/accessingyahoomail/f/What-Are-The-Yahoo-Mail-Imap-Settings.htm

Comment: I think that is for Mail Plus - a paid service of Yahoo Mail

Comment: I know that Yahoo supports IMAP in some way, because my Dad has a free Yahoo account and his iPad connects to it via IMAP. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Set your options (Gear symbol/Mail options) to show 200 messages per page.
2. In the search box enter a key phrase from the emails.
3. On the left side of the screen you can see a list of items you can use to filter the results (sender, folder, year, status). Sender Facebook might be a good one for you to select.
4. At the top of the list of emails just to the left of "sort by" there is a small box, check it. Now all the messages on that page are selected.
5. The buttons for "Delete/Move/Spam/actions" are now activated.
6. Move them to a folder. You can even create a new folder.
7. Repeat the last 3 steps.

Comment: This seems to be best way at the moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot more easier way to do that

1. Click on any mail by the sender
2. Once mail is opened, click on sender name
3. Select option from the drop down menu "Search for Messages From..."
4. Click on select all checkbox ( Near delete button on toolbar )
5. Click delete button to delete all mails from sender.

Answer (score 0):

In the new interface (late 2013), hover over any message and click on the magnifier glass (see below). This will filter all your emails by the respective sender.

[image]

Once you did this, in order to select *all* the emails you want to delete, you need to scroll all the way down to the bottom (Yahoo loads new emails as you scroll down) and then click on the checkbox in the actions menu (far left) and choose **All**. And then click **Delete** from the actions menu.

[image]